# Cellsize in sf::st_make_grid() seems to not relate to map units

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I am attempting to overlay a map with a grid using `sf`. My issues occur when trying to set the cell size of the grid.

```
demo(nc, ask = FALSE, echo = FALSE)
my_grid <- sf::st_make_grid(x = nc, cellsize = c(1, 4))
```

According a documentation (I found somewhere and can't dig it back up :-/ ) the cell size should be expressed in units of the underlying map. These are meters, see:

```
sf::st_length(nc)
Units: [m]
  [1] 141665.40 119928.97 ...
```

However, a look at the plot resulting from the code above clearly shows no grid cells of 1 by 4 meters, but much larger ones. Can you help and let us know how you would, if you wanted to, set the grid cell size to 1 x 4 meters?

```
plot(nc['NAME'])
plot(my_grid, add = TRUE)
```

The grid cellsize should be 1 by 4 meters, but it's clearly not:

[image: The grid cellsize should be 1 by 4 meters, but it's clearly not.]

Comment: Isn't the crs of nc 4326? If you want meters you need to project.

Answer (score 6):

It's because the nc dataset is in lat-long coordinates, so a cellsize of `c(1,4)` would be 1 degree by 4 degrees which is what your grid is showing. You have to project the data if you want the grid in units of meters. Note that EPSG 5070 probably isn't the best projection for this area; I just chose it for demonstration purposes. I didn't use 1 m x 4 m because I don't have enough ram on my computer to handle it, but you can see the input dimensions match the output.

```
st_crs(nc)$proj4string
# [1] "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs"


nc <- st_transform(nc, crs=st_crs(5070))
cs <- c(10000, 40000)
my_grid <- sf::st_make_grid(x = nc, 
                            cellsize=cs)

st_area(my_grid[1,]) == (min(cs) * max(cs)) %>% units::as_units("m^2")
# TRUE
```

Comment: How do we find the right projection for our data? E.g., if it is from Peru or France or Singapore, which projections would we choose? (I see that EPSG seems to be exclusive to the US.)